# Setting Precedence of Multiple @ControllerAdvice @ExceptionHandlers

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, exception

I have multiple classes annotated with `@ControllerAdvice`, each with an `@ExceptionHandler` method in.

One handles `Exception` with the intention that if no more specific handler is found, this should be used.

Sadly Spring MVC appears to be always using the most generic case (`Exception`) rather than more specific ones (`IOException` for example).

Is this how one would expect Spring MVC to behave? I'm trying to emulate a pattern from Jersey, which assesses each `ExceptionMapper` (equivalent component) to determine how far the declared type that it handles is from the exception that has been thrown, and always uses the nearest ancestor.

Answer (score 195, accepted):

> Is this how one would expect Spring MVC to behave?

As of Spring 4.3.7, here's how Spring MVC behaves: it uses [`HandlerExceptionResolver`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/HandlerExceptionResolver.html) instances to handle exceptions thrown by handler methods.

By default, the web MVC configuration registers a single `HandlerExceptionResolver` bean, a [`HandlerExceptionResolverComposite`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/handler/HandlerExceptionResolverComposite.html), which

> delegates to a list of other `HandlerExceptionResolvers`.

Those other resolvers are

1. `ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver`
2. `ResponseStatusExceptionResolver`
3. `DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver`

registered in that order. For the purpose of this question we only care about [`ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/method/annotation/ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver.html).

> An `AbstractHandlerMethodExceptionResolver` that resolves exceptions
>   through `@ExceptionHandler` methods.

At context initialization, Spring will generate a [`ControllerAdviceBean`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/method/ControllerAdviceBean.html) for each [`@ControllerAdvice`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/ControllerAdvice.html) annotated class it detects. The `ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver` will retrieve these from the context, and sort them using using [`AnnotationAwareOrderComparator`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/annotation/AnnotationAwareOrderComparator.html) which

> is an extension of `OrderComparator` that supports Spring's `Ordered`
>   interface as well as the `@Order` and `@Priority` annotations, with an
>   order value provided by an Ordered instance overriding a statically
>   defined annotation value (if any).

It'll then register an [`ExceptionHandlerMethodResolver`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/method/annotation/ExceptionHandlerMethodResolver.html) for each of these `ControllerAdviceBean` instances (mapping available `@ExceptionHandler` methods to the exception types they're meant to handle). These are finally added in the same order to a `LinkedHashMap` (which preserves iteration order).

When an exception occurs, the `ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver` will iterate through these `ExceptionHandlerMethodResolver` and use the first one that can handle the exception.

So the point here is: if you have a `@ControllerAdvice` with an `@ExceptionHandler` for `Exception` that gets registered before another `@ControllerAdvice` class with an `@ExceptionHandler` for a more specific exception, like `IOException`, that first one will get called. As mentioned earlier, you can control that registration order by having your `@ControllerAdvice` annotated class implement [`Ordered`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/Ordered.html) or annotating it with [`@Order`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/annotation/Order.html) or [`@Priority`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/annotation/Priority.html) and giving it an appropriate value.

Comment: Further, in case of multiple `@ExceptionHandler` methods within a `@ControllerAdvice`, the one handling the most specific superclass of the thrown exception is chosen.

Comment: In spring boot 2.3.3 it doesn't require @Order annotation on a subclass overriding a controller advice ExceptionHandler method from a parent controller advice class

Answer (score 124):

Sotirios Delimanolis was very helpful in his answer, on further investigation we found that, in spring 3.2.4 anyway, the code that looks for @ControllerAdvice annotations also checks for the presence of @Order annotations and sorts the list of ControllerAdviceBeans.

The resulting default order for all controllers without the @Order annotation is Ordered#LOWEST_PRECEDENCE which means if you have one controller that needs to be the lowest priority then ALL your controllers need to have a higher order.

Here's an example showing how to have two exception handler classes with ControllerAdvice and Order annotations that can serve appropriate responses when either a UserProfileException or RuntimeException occurs.

```
class UserProfileException extends RuntimeException {
}

@ControllerAdvice
@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
class UserProfileExceptionHandler {
    @ExceptionHandler(UserProfileException)
    @ResponseBody
    ResponseEntity<ErrorResponse> handleUserProfileException() {
        ....
    }
}

@ControllerAdvice
@Order(Ordered.LOWEST_PRECEDENCE)
class DefaultExceptionHandler {

    @ExceptionHandler(RuntimeException)
    @ResponseBody
    ResponseEntity<ErrorResponse> handleRuntimeException() {
        ....
    }
}
```

- See ControllerAdviceBean#initOrderFromBeanType()
- See ControllerAdviceBean#findAnnotatedBeans()
- See ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver#initExceptionHandlerAdviceCache()

Enjoy!

Answer (score 27):

The order of exception handlers can be changed using the [`@Order`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/annotation/Order.html) annotation.

For example:

```
import org.springframework.core.Ordered;
import org.springframework.core.annotation.Order;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ControllerAdvice;

@ControllerAdvice
@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
public class CustomExceptionHandler {

    //...

}
```

`@Order`'s value can be any integer.

Comment: Thank you for giving imports in your answer!

Answer (score 6):

I also found in the documentation that :

https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/4.3.4.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/method/annotation/ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver.html#getExceptionHandlerMethod-org.springframework.web.method.HandlerMethod-java.lang.Exception-

> ExceptionHandlerMethod
>
> protected ServletInvocableHandlerMethod
>   getExceptionHandlerMethod(HandlerMethod handlerMethod,
>                                Exception exception)
>
> Find an @ExceptionHandler method for the given
>   exception. **The default implementation searches methods in the class
>   hierarchy of the controller first and if not found, it continues
>   searching for additional @ExceptionHandler methods assuming some
>   @ControllerAdvice Spring-managed beans were detected**. Parameters:
>   handlerMethod - the method where the exception was raised (may be
>   null) exception - the raised exception Returns: a method to handle the
>   exception, or null

So this means that if you want to solve this issue, you will need to add your specific exception handler within the controller throwing those exception. ANd to define one and only ControllerAdvice handling the Global default exception handler.

This simplies the process and we don't need the Order annotation to handle the problem.

Answer (score 5):

you can also use a number value, like below

```
@Order(value = 100)
```

> Lower values have higher priority. The default value is * {@code
>   Ordered.LOWEST_PRECEDENCE},indicating lowest priority (losing to any
>   other * specified order value)

Comment: I like this approach more than @Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE) or @Order(Ordered.LOWEST_PRECEDENCE), because it gives you more flexibility and you can better structure the priority of multiple advice beans by assigning lower or higher value to the @Order

Answer (score 4):

Important Class to be handled :

```
@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
public class FunctionalResponseEntityExceptionHandler 
{
    private final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(FunctionalResponseEntityExceptionHandler.class);

    @ExceptionHandler(EntityNotFoundException.class)
    public final ResponseEntity<Object> handleFunctionalExceptions(EntityNotFoundException ex, WebRequest request)
    {
        logger.error(ex.getMessage() + " " + ex);
        ExceptionResponse exceptionResponse= new ExceptionResponse(new Date(), ex.getMessage(),
                request.getDescription(false),HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND.toString());
        return new ResponseEntity<>(exceptionResponse, HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
    }
}
```

Other Exceptions with Low priority

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class GlobalResponseEntityExceptionHandler extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler
{
    private final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(GlobalResponseEntityExceptionHandler.class);
    
    @ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
    public final ResponseEntity<Object> handleAllException(Exception ex, WebRequest request)
    {
        logger.error(ex.getMessage()+ " " + ex);
        ExceptionResponse exceptionResponse= new ExceptionResponse(new Date(), ex.toString(),
                request.getDescription(false),HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR.toString());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

There's a similar situation convered in the excellent "[Exception Handling in Spring MVC](http://spring.io/blog/2013/11/01/exception-handling-in-spring-mvc)" post on the Spring blog, in the section entitled [Global Exception Handling](http://spring.io/blog/2013/11/01/exception-handling-in-spring-mvc#global-exception-handling).  Their scenario involves checking for ResponseStatus annotations registered on the exception class, and if present, rethrowing the exception to let the framework handle them.  You might be able to use this general tactic - try to determine if there is a might be a more appropriate handler out there and rethrowing.

Alternatively, there's some other exception handling strategies covered that you might look at instead.

Answer (score 1):

If you want separate your exception handlers(like me), you can use `@Import` to do this.

```
@ControllerAdvice
class MyCustomExceptionHandler {
  ...
}
```

```
@ControllerAdvice
class MyOtherCustomExceptionHandler {
  ...
}
```

```
@Import({MyCustomExceptionHandler.class,MyOtherCustomExceptionHandler.class})
@ControllerAdvice
@Order(Ordered.LOWEST_PRECEDENCE)
class ApplicationExceptionHandler{
  //Generic exception handlers
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Spring Framework sorts **beans** annotated with `@ControllerAdvice` using [OrderComparator](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/OrderComparator.html).

However, `@ExceptionHandler` **methods** present **within a single class** are sorted using [ExceptionDepthComparator](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/ExceptionDepthComparator.html).

It means that a possible workaround is to put all `@ExceptionHandler` methods into a single class.

```
@ControllerAdvice
class ExceptionHandler {

    @ExceptionHandler(IOException.class)
    ResponseEntity<Object> handleIOException() {
        ....
    }

    @ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
    ResponseEntity<Object> handleException() {
        ....
    }
}
```