# Why @ExceptionHandler(MethodArgumentNotValidException.class) is ignored in favour of @ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, exception

I know that Exception is the Parent of all exceptions but I thought when you set @ExceptionHandler with specific exception class this should handle that specific exception.

Maybe you can point what I have missed in following code so MethodArgumentNotValidException will go into processValidationError method not processError method.

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class ExceptionHandler {

@ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
@ResponseBody
public ValidationErrorDTO processError(Exception e) {
    return processErrors(e);
  }
 }

  @ControllerAdvice
public class OtherExceptionHandler {

@ExceptionHandler(MethodArgumentNotValidException.class)
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
@ResponseBody
public ValidationErrorDTO processValidationError(MethodArgumentNotValidException ex) {
    return processErrors(ex);
}
}
```

Comment: Are you certain that `MethodArgumentNotValidException` is thrown and not some wrapper class?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis, won't [your answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19498378/setting-precedence-of-multiple-controlleradvice-exceptionhandlers/19500823#19500823) help here? :)

Comment: @MichałRybak Seems like OP only has one `@ControllerAdvice` class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After your edit it's clear that you have more than one `@ControllerAdvice` class.

In short, the problem is that your `ExceptionHandler` class (and its `@ExceptionHandler` for `Exception.class`) gets registered first by Spring, and because `Exception` handler matches any exception, it will be matched before Spring ever gets to more specific handlers defined.

You can read detailed explanation in @Sotirios answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19498378/setting-precedence-of-multiple-controlleradvice-exceptionhandlers/19500823#19500823).

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend you register only one `ControllerAdvice` and to make sure it extends `ResponseEntityExceptionHandler`, so the default handling of `MethodArgumentNotValidException` is not overwritten.

If you then wish to alter the logic of handling the `MethodArumentNotValidException`, you can override the `handleMethodArgumentNotValid` method.