# Write JUnit test for local @ExceptionHandler

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, junit

I have the following controller:

```
class Controller {

    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
    @RequestMapping(value = "/verifyCert", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public void verifyCertificate() throws CertificateExpiredException, CertificateNotYetValidException {
        certificate.checkValidity();
    }

    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN)
    @ExceptionHandler({CertificateExpiredException.class, CertificateNotYetValidException.class})
    public void handleCertificateValidityException(Exception e) {}
}
```

My goal is to that controller redirects to exception handler if certificate is not valid.

Comment: Because that is what you have setup. You are only testing the controller not the remaining infrastructure, if you want that you need to setup a full application context.

Comment: Notice the `standaloneSetup`. Check the other `MockMvcBuilders` methods.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using `standaloneSetup` all you are doing is performing the setup for the specific controller.

If you don't want to configure the whole application context (which you would do with `webAppContextSetup` instead of `standaloneSetup`), you can manually setup the exception handler by changing your code to:

```
 @Before
 public void setup() throws IOException {
     MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
     mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(controller).setHandlerExceptionResolvers(new ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver()).build();
 }

 @Test
 public void test() throws Exception {
     mockMvc.perform(get("/verifyCert.controller").contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)).andExpect(status().isForbidden());
 }
```

This works because [ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/method/annotation/ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver.html) is the class that Spring MVC uses to handle exceptions based on the `@ExceptionHandler` annotation

Check out [one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25604448/2504224) of my older relevant answers that covers an ever more difficult case (the use of `@ControllerAdvice` on a class that contains `@ExceptionHandler`).

Comment: Thanks, I've tried your approach. But unfortunatly I get the following error: org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: @fashuser That's weird! I ran this code and everything worked as expected! Can you update your question with this info?

Comment: I've added full stacktrace to question.

Comment: @fashuser What version of Spring are you using?

Comment: @fashuser I was not able to reproduce your problem with either Spring 4 or Spring 3.2

Answer (score -1):

A property in your class `net.scansafe.scancentre21.springmvc.web.easyid.ManageSamlAuthenticationRealmController.verifySecondarySamlSpCertificate(ManageSamlAuthenticationRealmController.java)` is null.

You can debug the method of the class to find it. You need to add a @Autowired to this property for injection.

Answer (score -1):

I've Solved In this way :

```
@Test(expected=MyException.class)
public void shouldThrowException() throws IOException, Exception {

    //Mock Response Controller 
    when(client.mymethod(any(MyInputClassOfController.class)))
        .thenReturn(mockedResponse);

    when(innerClassInController.myMethodThatInvokeTheException(mock(MyClass.class)))
        .thenThrow(new MyException("message"));

    this.mockMvc.perform(post("/root/search/")
        .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8)
        .content( "null Request to throw the exception"))
        .andExpect(status().isBadRequest());
}
```