# Rest Assured + Mock MVC @ControllerAdvice

Tags: rest, unit-testing, rest-assured, mockmvc

In my project I am using Rest Assured MockMVC with the following dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.jayway.restassured</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-mock-mvc</artifactId>
    <version>2.9.0</version>
</dependency>
```

And my test class looks like:

```
TestController testController = new TestController();
@Before
public void configureRestAssuredForController() {
    RestAssuredMockMvc.standaloneSetup(testController);
}
```

I have a couple of ExceptionHandlers defined in the controller class.
In my JUnit tests I could verify the request paths and the handlers when defined in the controller class.

However - When I moved the handlers to a separate class with `@ControllerAdvice`, handlers are not being invoked from the tests.

I understood that it is because of the standalone set up for the controller,which probably could not load handlers defined in another class.

But I couldn't figure out how do I add the exception handlers to the RestAssuredMockMvc,in standalone mode to make this work.

I am struggling and any help is much appreciated please.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I edited your question to indent your code sample by 4 spaces so that it renders properly - please see the editing help for more information on formatting. Please edit in to provide any additional detail that's necessary to identify the specific problem. Good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25787476/2239713) I've created a solution that works great for me:

```
/**
 * Initializes GlobalExceptionHandler advice using the StaticApplicationContext with the single bean.
 *
 * @return HandlerExceptionResolver instantiated based on the GlobalExceptionHandler
 */
private HandlerExceptionResolver initGlobalExceptionHandlerResolvers() {
    StaticApplicationContext applicationContext = new StaticApplicationContext();
    applicationContext.registerSingleton("exceptionHandler", GlobalExceptionHandler.class);

    WebMvcConfigurationSupport webMvcConfigurationSupport = new WebMvcConfigurationSupport();
    webMvcConfigurationSupport.setApplicationContext(applicationContext);

    return webMvcConfigurationSupport.handlerExceptionResolver();
}

@Before
public void setup() {
    HandlerExceptionResolver handlerExceptionResolver = initGlobalExceptionHandlerResolvers();

    RestAssuredMockMvc.standaloneSetup(
            MockMvcBuilders
                    .standaloneSetup(controller)
                    .setHandlerExceptionResolvers(handlerExceptionResolver)
    );
}
```

So my GlobalExceptionHandler is initialized using StaticApplicationContext and then I retrieve handlerExceptionResolver from it and pass it into RestAssuredMockMvc standaloneSetup

Comment: Have you got a copy of the rest of your code. With Controller and Test Class deceleration?

Answer (score 3):

I upgraded Spring to 4.3.1.RELEASE and did the following to make it work -

```java
GlobalControllerExceptionHandler globalControllerExceptionHandler = new GlobalControllerExceptionHandler();
    @Before 
    public void given_rest_assured_is_configured_with_cloud_study_controller()
        throws Exception {
        mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(cloudStudyCountryController)
            .setControllerAdvice(globalControllerExceptionHandler).build();
        RestAssuredMockMvc.mockMvc(mockMvc);
        dataObj.setCloudDataObjectCreateProcessor(createprocessor);
    }
```