# How to set priority in ExceptionHandling via ControllerAdvice

Tags: spring, exception

I was implement 2 ControllersAdvice to. handle exception
CommonAdvice and  UserAdvice

Common Advice

```
@ControllerAdvice(annotations = RestController.class)
public class CommonAdvice {

    @ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
    public ResponseEntity<ExceptionBean> handleException(Exception e) {
        ExceptionBean exception = new ExceptionBean(Causes.ANOTHER_CAUSE);
        return new ResponseEntity<ExceptionBean>(exception, HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
    }

}
```

UserAdvice

```
@ControllerAdvice(assignableTypes = { requestUserMapper.class })
public class UserAdvice {

    @ExceptionHandler(NotUniqueUserLoginException.class)
    public ResponseEntity<ExceptionBean> handleAlreadyFound(NotUniqueUserLoginException e) {
        System.out.println("this is me : " + Causes.USER_ALREADY_EXIST.toString());
        ExceptionBean exception = new ExceptionBean(Causes.USER_ALREADY_EXIST);
        return new ResponseEntity<ExceptionBean>(exception, HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
    }
```

And now, when I throw  NotUniqueUserException, this is a CommonAdvice which handle and exception.

I tested and UserAdvice works fine. 
There is the way to set priority on this classes ?

@Edit - add Controllel Mapping

```
@RequestMapping(value = "add", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ResponseEntity<GT_User> addUser(@RequestBody GT_User newUser) throws NotUniqueUserLoginException, Exception {

    if (this.userService.exist(newUser.getLogin())) {
        throw new NotUniqueUserLoginException(Causes.USER_ALREADY_EXIST.toString());
    } else {
        GT_User addesUser = this.userService.addUser(newUser);
        return new ResponseEntity<GT_User>(addesUser, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}
```

Comment: can you provide the  actual controller code and exception stacktrace?

Comment: here you are.  But as I told already,  When. hadleException() is commented, the handleAlreadyFound() works fine.   When I add handleAlreadyfound() int the same class, before handleException) it works too.  So, this Is only a problem with piority... I think..

Comment: OK...  sorry... I have found solution.  The problem was.. MY ENGLISH...  I was searched priority.  instead of ORDER...   Simple annotation @Order resolve my problem.

Comment: Great! You could post the working solution as an answer and accept your own answer!

Comment: eeee how can I do this  ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Setting Precedence of Multiple @ControllerAdvice @ExceptionHandlers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19498378/setting-precedence-of-multiple-controlleradvice-exceptionhandlers)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To set Higher priority to an ControllerAdvice on add :

```
import org.springframework.core.Ordered;
import org.springframework.core.annotation.Order;
import com.genealogytree.webapplication.dispatchers.requestUserMapper;

@ControllerAdvice(assignableTypes = { requestUserMapper.class })
@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
public class UserAdvice {
...
}
```

To set Lower priority to an ControolerAdvice on add

```
import org.springframework.core.Ordered;
import org.springframework.core.annotation.Order;
import com.genealogytree.webapplication.dispatchers.requestUserMapper;

@ControllerAdvice(assignableTypes = { requestUserMapper.class })
@Order(Ordered.LOWEST_PRECEDENCE)
public class CommonAdvice {
...
}
```