# @ExceptionHandler for type Exception not called for Spring exception in custom ResponseEntityExceptionHandler

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

After reading some blog posts about making a custom exception handler for Spring, I wrote the following class:

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class RestExceptionHandler extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {
    @ExceptionHandler(value = Exception.class)
    @ResponseBody
    public ResponseEntity<Object> exceptionHandler(Exception e) {
        HashMap<String, Object> msg = new HashMap<>(2);
        msg.put("error", HttpStatus.PRECONDITION_FAILED.value());
        msg.put("message", "Something went wrong");
        return new ResponseEntity<>(msg, HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
    }
}
```

The intent is to send `msg` in the JSON response instead of giving away the Spring exception what was thrown for whatever reason.

This class isn't working, however.

When I hit, say, and invalid endpoint for my server API, I get the default response payload:

```
{
  "timestamp": 1449238700342,
  "status": 405,
  "error": "Method Not Allowed",
  "exception": "org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException",
  "message": "Request method 'POST' not supported",
  "path": "/bad_enpoint"
}
```

What am I missing?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you elaborate on "isnt't working"? It doesn't get called? It does, but it fails?

Comment: I updated the question with more info. It doesn't get called, I still the Spring default JSON back with the Spring expection being "exposed"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your handler will not be called because you want to map `Exception` to your custom error response but Spring MVC most likely already has one exception handler registered for `Exception` class. It also has one that handles `HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException` for sure.

It is not a great idea however, to overwrite entire Spring MVC exception handling/mapping anyway. You should only care about specific exceptions - ones that you define.

Please read [this article](https://spring.io/blog/2013/11/01/exception-handling-in-spring-mvc) for a bit more insight into Spring MVC exception handling.

Comment: Thanks for the article, I'm fine with Spring having its own handlers. I don't like, however, the fact that Spring gives away too much about the internals of an application by sending a response with stuff like `"exception": "org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException",`

Comment: Ok it is a valid point. Try to add @Order annotation with the HIGHEST PRECEDENCE set. See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19498378/setting-precedence-of-multiple-controlleradvice-exceptionhandlers

Comment: This link to the use of `@Order` is exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 2):

1. You don't need to extend ResponseEntityExceptionHandler to make it work.
2. Setting two HttpStatuses is reaaaaaly bad idea.

```java
    @ControllerAdvice
    public class RestExceptionHandler  {
        @ExceptionHandler(value = Exception.class)
        @ResponseBody
        public ResponseEntity<String> exceptionHandler(Exception e) {
            return new ResponseEntity<>("Something went wrong", HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
        }
    }
```

Comment: I still get the same JSON response (see bottom of my question) instead of `"Something went wrong"`

Comment: The `@ControllerAdvice` is aspect for controllers. Your AJAX call didn't even get to controller - from response I guess you don't have POST implemented on `/bad_enpoint` controller (or no controller at all)

Comment: I have a `@RestController` class that defines the endpoints. Should @RestController and @ControllerAdvice be annotated on the same class?

Comment: No, consider `@ControllerAdvice` class as aspect for all controllers. Could you paste your `@RestController` class?

Comment: Unfortunately I can't, it is a proprietary application. Thank you for your help.