# Spring boot @ExceptionHandler is not reached

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-boot, exception, throwable

I am working on exception handling for spring boot application. I have created my own Exception class witch I am throwing, everything is working fine I get exception in console but I can't reach my @ExceptionHandler method.

My class that throws exception:

```
@Override
public AuctionBody insertNewAuction(AuctionBody auctionBody, int ownerId, String AUCTION_TYPE) {
    try {
        SimpleJdbcInsert simpleJdbcInsert = new SimpleJdbcInsert(dataSource).withTableName("auctions")
                .usingGeneratedKeyColumns("id");
        Map<String, Object> parameters = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        parameters.put("title", auctionBody.getTitle());
        parameters.put("type", auctionBody.getType());
        parameters.put("start_time", Timestamp.valueOf(auctionBody.getStartDate()));
        parameters.put("end_time", Timestamp.valueOf(auctionBody.getEndDate()));
        parameters.put("quantity", auctionBody.getItemQuantity());
        parameters.put("starting_price", auctionBody.getStartingPrice());
        parameters.put("currency", auctionBody.getCurrency());
        parameters.put("status", auctionBody.getStatus());
        parameters.put("description", null);
        parameters.put("allow_bid_for_quantity", auctionBody.isAllowToBidForQuantity());
        parameters.put("buy_out_price", auctionBody.getBuyOutPrice());
        parameters.put("owner_id", ownerId);
        parameters.put("buy_out_price", auctionBody.getBuyOutPrice());
        parameters.put("quantity_left", auctionBody.getItemQuantity());
        parameters.put("uuid", auctionBody.getAuctionIdUrlOwner());
        parameters.put("allow_buy_out", auctionBody.isAllowBuyOut());
        parameters.put("link", auctionBody.getLink());
        auctionBody.setId((Integer) simpleJdbcInsert.executeAndReturnKey(parameters));


        insertNewAuctionPictures(auctionBody, auctionBody.getId());
        if (AUCTION_TYPE.equals("FullAuction")) {
            insertPeopleToInvite(auctionBody);
        }

        return auctionBody;
    }catch (DataAccessException e){
        throw new JdbcExceptions("Cant add auction");
    }
}
```

Exception is thrown because of description being null (I did it just to check if i'll get to my created exception handler or not).

The Exception class looks like this:

```
public class JdbcExceptions extends RuntimeException {
public JdbcExceptions(String message) {
    super(message);
}
```

}

And the exception handler controller class looks like this:

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class ExceptionHandlingController {

    @ExceptionHandler(JdbcExceptions.class)
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
    public String getJdbcException(JdbcExceptions ex){
        return "redirect:/html/errorPage";
    }
}
```

I know that it should work and I am sure that I have some kind of bad configuration that is making my @ExceptionHandler unreachable, but I haven't found the answer. 
Also ExceptionHandlingController class is created on application run.

Main class:

```
package com.visma.seli;

import com.visma.seli.config.properties.repository.DatabaseProperties;
import com.visma.seli.config.properties.repository.RepositoryProperties;
import org.springframework.boot.Banner;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder;
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.EnableConfigurationProperties;
import org.springframework.boot.web.support.SpringBootServletInitializer;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.EnableScheduling;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet;

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableConfigurationProperties({RepositoryProperties.class, DatabaseProperties.class})
@EnableScheduling
@ComponentScan()
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class SeliApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext ctx = SpringApplication.run(SeliApplication.class, args);
        DispatcherServlet dispatcherServlet = (DispatcherServlet)ctx.getBean("dispatcherServlet");
        dispatcherServlet.setThrowExceptionIfNoHandlerFound(true);
    }

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder builder) {
        return builder.bannerMode(Banner.Mode.OFF).sources(SeliApplication.class);
    }

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder createSpringApplicationBuilder() {
        return new SpringApplicationBuilder().bannerMode(Banner.Mode.OFF);
    }
}
```

No other Exception handler in my application and after throw I get that message that I set `Cant add auction`

Comment: So what exactly is happening when the `JdbcExceptions` is thrown? Do you have any log in the console? Do you have any other exception handlers in your application?

Comment: Can you add the code for SpringBoot main class and ExceptionHandlingController inlcuding import statements ?

Comment: provide your configuration for spring boot. It seems that @ControlerAdvice is not detected.

Comment: @TechBreak but if it wouldn't be detected would it call `ExceptionHandlingController` constructor.

Comment: I think you are missing exception handler resolver?
This might help.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19498378/setting-precedence-of-multiple-controlleradvice-exceptionhandlers

Comment: is your exception is rollback? i think your problem is in transactional.spring throw rollback exception instead your custom exception.because your catch dose not work.create break pint .you see dont work.

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding @EnableWebMvc to your config file

```
 @Configuration
 @EnableWebMvc
 @ComponentScan(...)
 public class MyAppConfiguration {

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone encounters this problem in the future, try setting up `annotations` property, that is

```
@RestControllerAdvice(annotations = [RestController::class])  // without `[]` if you're not using kotlin
class SomeExceptionHandler
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can't find solution for error "@ExceptionHandler cannot be reached with java8+" maybe you made same mistake as I did. I named my exception handler class as "ExceptionHandler" which is same as name of annotation @ExceptionHandler. After correction, my IDE was able to import as:

```
"org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ExceptionHandler;"
```