# How to determine if an exception is a ClientAbortException

Tags: java, spring, maven, tomcat, exception

So I get the following exception when a user cancels a request on my web application hosted on a Tomcat application server, with dependency management handled through Maven:

```
ClientAbortException:  java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.realWriteBytes(OutputBuffer.java:406)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.buf.ByteChunk.flushBuffer(ByteChunk.java:480)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.buf.ByteChunk.append(ByteChunk.java:366)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.writeBytes(OutputBuffer.java:431)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.write(OutputBuffer.java:419)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteOutputStream.write(CoyoteOutputStream.java:91)
    ...
```

I have a Spring `@ControllerAdvice` class that handles all exceptions, and sends an email.

```
@ExceptionHandler(value = Exception.class)
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
public ResponseEntity defaultErrorHandler(final HttpServletRequest request, final Principal principal, final Exception e) {

    //send email with details of error

    return ResponseEntity(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
}
```

However, I do not want to send the email if it is this `ClientAbortException`.

I would like to do something like this:

```
if (!(e instanceof ClientAbortException)) {
    //send email with details of error
}
```

But `ClientAbortException` does not seem to be on my classpath, as it is an exception included in a tomcat server-level lib.

I could check if `e instance of SocketException`, but I might miss other `SocketException`s that I care about. My next idea was something like:

```
e instanceof SocketException && e.getMessage().contains("Connection reset")
```

But it seems like there should be a more straightforward way of doing this.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I look at java doc and the [ClientAbortException](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/api/org/apache/catalina/connector/ClientAbortException.html) is child of IOException so you can't use instance of to SocketException.

On my version of tomcat the code that throws the exception is:

```
if (cnt > 0) {
        // real write to the adapter
        outputChunk.setBytes(buf, off, cnt);
        try {
            coyoteResponse.doWrite(outputChunk);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // An IOException on a write is almost always due to
            // the remote client aborting the request.  Wrap this
            // so that it can be handled better by the error dispatcher.
            throw new ClientAbortException(e);
        }
    }
```

I think you just create a new exception handler for you client abort exception. Don't use instance on different exceptions.

```
@ExceptionHandler(value = ClientAbortException.class)
public ResponseEntity<ErrorResponse> handleClientAbort(Exception ex, HttpServletRequest req) {
    //YOUR HANDLER IMPLEMENTATION

}
```

You can use the @Order annotation to configure the [precedence of exceptions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19498378/setting-precedence-of-multiple-controlleradvice-exceptionhandlers).