# Spring: Different exception handler for RestController and Controller

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-mvc, exception

In Spring you can set up "global" exception handler via @ControllerAdvice and @ExceptionHandler annotation. I'm trying to utilize this mechanism to have two global exception handlers:

- `RestControllerExceptionHandler` - which should return error responses as json for any controller annotated with `@RestController`
- `ControllerExceptionHandler` - which should print error message to the screen for any other controller (annottated with `@Controller`)

The problem is that when I declare these two exception handlers spring always uses the `ControllerExceptionHandler` and never `RestControllerExceptionHandler` to handle the exception.

How to make this work ? 
BTW: I tried to use @Order annotation but this does not seem to work.

Here are my exception handlers:

```
// should handle all exception for classes annotated with         
@ControllerAdvice(annotations = RestController.class)
public class RestControllerExceptionHandler {


  @ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
  public ResponseEntity<ErrorResponse> handleUnexpectedException(Exception e) {

    // below object should be serialized to json
    ErrorResponse errorResponse = new ErrorResponse("asdasd"); 

    return new ResponseEntity<ErrorResponse>(errorResponse, HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
  }

// should handle exceptions for all the other controllers
@ControllerAdvice(annotations = Controller.class)
public class ControllerExceptionHandler {


  @ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
  public ResponseEntity<String> handleUnexpectedException(Exception e) {
    return new ResponseEntity<String>("Unexpected exception, HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
  }


}
}
```

When I remove `ControllerExceptionHandler` than `RestControllerExceptionHandler` is correctly called by spring (only for classes annotated with `@RestController`).... but when I add `ControllerExceptionHandler` than all goes via `ControllerExceptionHandler`. Why?

Comment: [This article](http://blog.codeleak.pl/2013/11/controlleradvice-improvements-in-spring.html) that describes a similar concept does not define any parameters to default controller advice (i.e. there's no `annotations` property in it). Have you tried if that works?

Comment: @M.Prokhorov: This is exactly what I'm trying to achieve. And as I look at the article I'm doing exactly the same. but for me this does not work for some reason :/

Comment: @M.Prokhorov: I figured it out. You're article was helpful for digging into this problem. I ended up with a bug in spring (see my own answer). Thanks again.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

After some deeper investigation it seems that the alphabetical order matters :/.

When I renamed my `RestControllerExceptionHandler` to `ARestControllerExceptionHandler` (which alphabetically precedes `ControllerExceptionHandler`) all works as expected! `ARestControllerExceptionHandler` correctly handles exceptions from `RestControllers` and `ControllerExceptionHandler` handles exception from other controllers.

I created a bug in spring for this: https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-15432

--- EDIT:

I received the answer for SPR-15432 where it is suggested that this case can be solved with `@Order` (`org.springframework.core.annotation.Order`) annotation or by implementing Ordered interface.

This did not work for me before, but it seems that *I have imported wrong `@Order` annotation.* (from log4j2 instead of spring). After fixing this it works. Fixed version is following:

```
// should handle all exception for classes annotated with         
@ControllerAdvice(annotations = RestController.class)
@Order(1) // NOTE: order 1 here
public class RestControllerExceptionHandler {


  @ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
  public ResponseEntity<ErrorResponse> handleUnexpectedException(Exception e) {

    // below object should be serialized to json
    ErrorResponse errorResponse = new ErrorResponse("asdasd"); 

    return new ResponseEntity<ErrorResponse>(errorResponse, HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
  }
}
// should handle exceptions for all the other controllers
@ControllerAdvice(annotations = Controller.class)
@Order(2)  // NOTE: order 2 here
public class ControllerExceptionHandler {


  @ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
  public ResponseEntity<String> handleUnexpectedException(Exception e) {
    return new ResponseEntity<String>("Unexpected exception, HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
  }
}
```

Comment: That may indeed be a bug, but it also very well may not be, it may be just an implementation detail of Spring reflection facilities that won't warrant a fix in your case. Try to look into ordering your advices, which may be done as suggested in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19500823/7470253).

Answer (score 11):

That's happening because @RestController annotation is itself an @Controller as well so Spring is considering the @ControllerAdvice with `annotation = Controller.class` for both.

You may try another [method](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/ControllerAdvice.html#annotations--) to define the subset of Controllers that the @ControllerAdvice will have effect, so here are some solutions:

---

#### Solution 1

1. Create a new Annotation @NotRestController:

   ```
   @Target({ElementType.TYPE})
   @Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
       public @interface NotRestController {
   }
   ```
2. Mark controllers that are not @RestController with both @Controller and @NotRestController:

   ```
   @Controller
   @NotRestController
   @RequestMapping("/controller")
   public class SampleController {
   }
   ```
3. Use `NotRestController.class` on `ControllerExceptionHandler`:

   ```
   @ControllerAdvice(annotations = NotRestController.class)
   public class ControllerExceptionHandler {
   ```

I've created a sample project with `Solution 1` and shared it on Github:

https://github.com/brunocleite/springexceptionhandlertest

---

#### Solution 2

1. Move your @RestController classes into a package `foo.bar` and your @Controller classes into another package `foo.nuk`.
2. Use `basePackages` property of `@ControllerAdvice` instead of `annotations`:

   ```
   @ControllerAdvice(basePackages={"foo.bar"})
   public class RestControllerExceptionHandler {

   @ControllerAdvice(basePackages={"foo.nuk"})
   public class ControllerExceptionHandler {
   ```

Best regards!

Comment: +1, however, I'm aware of other options for @Controller advice (as described in solution 1), but I do not want to use them because I want to utilize existing RestController anotation. The solution 1 is ok , but sill I do not want to add extra unnecessary annotations.

Answer (score 1):

**This was my solution. It eliminates the need to create additional annotations.**

1. Create 2 base controllers.

```
@Controller
public class BaseController

@Controller
public class BaseRestController
```

2. Extend each controller with chosen base controller.

```
@Controller
public class UserController extends BaseController

@RestController
public class UserRestController extends BaseRestController
```

3. Create 2 global controllers and include only the extended base class in each.

```
@ControllerAdvice(assignableTypes = BaseController.class)
public class GlobalController

@ControllerAdvice(assignableTypes = BaseRestController.class)
public class GlobalRestController
```

Answer (score 1):

To further build on the solution 1 of @bruno-leite:

You can define a meta-annotation so you only need to 1 annotation each time insted of 2:

```
import org.springframework.core.annotation.AliasFor;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;

import java.lang.annotation.*;

/**
 * Alias annotation for @Controller so that @ControllerAdvice instances can
 * target the web controllers separately from the rest controllers.
 */
@Target({ElementType.TYPE})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Documented
@Controller
public @interface WebController {
    @AliasFor(
            annotation = Controller.class
    )
    String value() default "";
}
```

Use it on the web controller(s):

```
@WebController
@RequestMapping("/customers")
public class CustomerController {
```

Finally define a `@ControllerAdvice` that only targets the web controllers like this:

```
@ControllerAdvice(annotations = WebController.class)
public class GlobalControllerAdvice {

    @ModelAttribute("displayName")
    public String getDisplayName(@AuthenticationPrincipal KeycloakAuthenticationToken principal) {
        if (principal != null) {
            String givenName = principal.getAccount().getKeycloakSecurityContext().getToken().getGivenName();
            String familyName = principal.getAccount().getKeycloakSecurityContext().getToken().getFamilyName();
            return givenName + " " + familyName;
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

(This example ensures that my Thymeleaf templates always have the `displayName` attribute, but can be easily adjusted for the exception handlers as well)

Answer (score -4):

Use order to fix error:

```
@Order(1)
@ControllerAdvice(annotations = RestController.class)
public class ErrorRestControllerAdvice {
}

@Order(2)
@ControllerAdvice(annotations = Controller.class)
public class ErrorControllerAdvice {
}
```

Comment: This solution was already posted by me. this answer does not bring anything new to the topic