# Spring @ExceptionHandler behaviour

Tags: java, spring, exception

Lets say I'm using **@ExceptionHandler** in my application.

If I define :

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class MyExceptionHandler {

    @ExceptionHandler(value = Exception.class)
    public boolean generic(Exception e) {
        return e;
    }

    @ExceptionHandler(value =MyException.class)
    public boolean myException(MyException e) {
        return e;
    }
}
```

Il my controller throws a **MyException**, will the **generic** exception handler be triggered too or only the best match with for the exception will be executed (here the MyException handler) ?

Comment: This may help you : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19498378/setting-precedence-of-multiple-controlleradvice-exceptionhandlers

Comment: Yes, thank you ! The "When an exception occurs, the ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver will iterate through these ExceptionHandlerMethodResolver and use the first one that can handle the exception." part was exactly what I needed.

Comment: And you can order them with `@Order` if you need so.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The **exception handler** will try to find the **specific exception**(`MyException`) **handler** firstly, if not it will try to find the **generic exception**(`Exception`).

so for your example, when controller `throw` `MyException`, the handler will invoke the `MyException` handler.

> An exception argument: declared as a general Exception or as a
>   more  specific exception. This also serves as a mapping hint if the
>   annotation itself does not narrow the exception types through its
>   {@link #value()}. Request and/or response objects (Servlet API
>   or Portlet API).

reference: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/5f4d1a4628513ab34098fa3f92ba03aa20fc4204/spring-web/src/main/java/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/ExceptionHandler.java#L33

Comment: Ok, so you say that only one Handler will be triggered : the one with the best match.