# How does spring manage ExceptionHandler priority?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, exceptionhandler

Giving this controller

```
@GetMapping("/test")
@ResponseBody
public String test() {
  if (!false) {
    throw new IllegalArgumentException();
  }

  return "blank";
}

@ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
@ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
@ResponseBody
public String handleException(Exception e) {
  return "Exception handler";
}

@ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
@ExceptionHandler(IllegalArgumentException.class)
@ResponseBody
public String handleIllegalException(IllegalArgumentException e) {
  return "IllegalArgumentException handler";
}
```

Both **ExceptionHandler** match the `IllegalArgumentException` because it's a child of `Exception` class.

When I reach `/test` endpoint, the method `handleIllegalException` is called. If I throw a `NullPointerException`, the method `handleException` is called.

How does spring knows that it should execute the `handleIllegalException` method and not the `handleException` method ? How does it manage the priority when multiple **ExceptionHandler** match an Exception ?

(I thought the order or the **ExceptionHandler** declarations was important, but even if I declare `handleIllegalException` before `handleException`, the result is the same)

Comment: there is an annotation `@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)`

Comment: yes but in my example I didn't set any `@Order`, and the `handleIllegalException` method is called, why not the `handleException` method ? Spring seems to manage the order by itself when no Order is specified...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19500823/3003337

Comment: @surya your link doesn't answer to my question, it speaks about the `@Order` annotation. It doesn't give any explanation about the default order when multiple `ExceptionHandler` match an Exception

Comment: With two classes of @controlleradvice you can guarantee order

Answer (score 16):

Spring MVC provides many different methods for Exception handling definitions.

In general, it will try to find the most "specific" exception handler registered to handle the exception. If there is no such a handler, it will try to check for the superclass of exception, maybe there is a handler for it, if it's not found as well, it will go one more level up and so on and so forth, from the most specific to the most general.

If you want to see it in the code of Spring, an entry point to learn this topic would be:

```
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver
```

This class resolves the exceptions registered through `@ExceptionHandler` methods out of the beans registered in the application context. This class, in turn, uses the another class `org.springframework.web.method.annotation.ExceptionHandlerMethodResolver`
which is responsible for mapping all the methods marked with `@ExceptionHandler` annotation.

Comment: And `ExceptionDepthComparator`.

Comment: hum I opened the source code of `ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver`, I think the alogorithm is in the method `getExceptionHandlerMethod` but I don't see where is the code responsible for **finding the most "specific" exception handler registered**

Comment: I didn't see the use of `ExceptionDepthComparator` in the `ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver`

Comment: I don't suppose there is a part of the docs you can link to as well?

Comment: Olivier, it's used in `org.springframework.web.method.annotation.ExceptionHandlerMethodResolver#getMappedMethod`