# Bind Exception Handling to @ControllerAdvice class only

Tags: java, spring, exception, spring-annotations

I have a controller class with REST methods that can throw various exceptions. I have decided to handle these exceptions in a separate class using the @ControllerAdvice and @ExceptionHandler for my handler methods.
However, I have the problem, that my REST methods use an annotation from another library. This library catches an exception that my REST method throws as well.
Now that I am handling the exceptions globally and not via try/catch in the REST method directly, my exception is always caught by the other library and not by my own handler method. Apparently, that other method in the library I am using wins due to the annotation.
How can I bind the exception handling to my own class to prevent it from being caught by anyone else?

My REST method:

```
@SomeLibraryAnnotation
@PostMapping(path = "/add", consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public HttpEntity< ? > addItem(@RequestHeader HttpHeaders headers, @RequestBody MyDTO myDTO)
  throws UnsupportedOperationException {
  doSomethingWith(myDTO);
  return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.CREATED).build();
}
```

My Exception Handler class:

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class MyExceptionHandler {

 @ExceptionHandler(UnsupportedOperationException.class)
 public ResponseEntity<?> handleUnsupportedOperationException(UnsupportedOperationException e) {        
    return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN).body(e.getMessage());
 }
}
```

As the library method also catches the UnsupportedOperationException, it wins due to the @SomeLibraryAnnotation and the exception is never handled in my handler class.

Answer (score 0):

You might try using `@Order` or `@Priority` in the `MyExceptionHandler` class, as discussed in [Setting Precedence of Multiple @ControllerAdvice @ExceptionHandlers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19498378/setting-precedence-of-multiple-controlleradvice-exceptionhandlers).

That would give Spring an opportunity to use your class instead of the one specified by the `@SomeLibraryAnnotation`. However, without knowing how Spring interprets that other annotation at context initialization, that's just a guess.

Comment: Thanx for the answer. I already tried both annotations. But it didn't work. I think they only work if I have multiple classes with ControllerAdvice annotations to prioritize them. But they do not have any effect if I use some custom annotation of a library that happens to catch the same exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried to write `@ExceptionHandler` inside your controller? Like:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/path")
public class TheController {

     @ExceptionHandler(UnsupportedOperationException.class)
     public ResponseEntity<?> handleUnsupportedOperationException(UnsupportedOperationException e) {        
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN).body(e.getMessage());
     }
}
```

Maybe that would pickup and exception with higher priority. It's hard to answer not knowing what `@SomeLibraryAnnotation` is...

Answer (score 0):

Those are simply Java Language rules, i.e. exception is no longer *unhandled*, as it was handled (caught in a catch block) by your other library. What you can do it is to re-throw (maybe conditionally) another exception in your library which caught original exception and see if `@ExceptionHandler` will handle it. It might not because `@ExceptionHandler` is handling exceptions thrown in Controller classes.

Second approach would be to throw exception which is only handled in @ExceptionHandler and then re-throw it be handled in other library.

In other words you need to choose where to handled first originally thrown exception.

Third approach would be use AOP interceptor `@AfterThrowing` or `@Around` and then execute whatever logic you want within.

Essence : There is no way to handle exception in two places at one time. Does it make sense?