# Spring WebExceptionHandler Order

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, error-handling, spring-webflux

In my Spring Webflux application I have a `@ControllerAdvice` annotated class that implements `WebExceptionHandler`, with its `@Order` set to -2,  and my idea is for it to be a global exception handler.

In this class I check the type of the `Throwable` received and handle it in the appropriate way, like this:

```
@Component
@Slf4j
@Order(-2)
@ControllerAdvice
public class CustomWebExceptionHandler implements WebExceptionHandler {

    @Override
    public Mono<Void> handle(ServerWebExchange exchange, Throwable ex) {
           if (ex instanceof ResponseStatusException) {
                ... do something
           }
           if (ex instanceof DomainException) {
                ... do something else
           }
}
```

In one of these "... do something" blocks I've made a mistake and an `IllegalArgumentException` was thrown. I thought it would be handled by this same class but it ended up being handled by the `DefaultErrorWebExceptionHandler`, that has `@Order(-1)`.

My question is: is it possible to have this `IllegalArgumentException` be handled by my `CustomWebExceptionHandler` instead?

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't need order here unless you have multiple handlers. From the code above I see that you have a `CustomWebExceptionHandler` annotated with `ControllerAdvice`. By default the methods in an `@ControllerAdvice` apply globally to all Controllers. Now to catch all exceptions **thrown by those targeted controllers** you can just simply define a method with `@ExceptionHandler` with throwable as parameter, something like this shall work for you:

```
    @ControllerAdvice
    public class CustomWebExceptionHandler {
        @ExceptionHandler
        public ResponseEntity handleExceptions(Throwable ex)
        {
           if (ex instanceof ResponseStatusException) {
                ... do something
           }
           if (ex instanceof DomainException) {
                ... do something else
           }
        }
    }
```

You can have multiple Exception handlers(per exception) if you wish see detailed answer here [Setting Precedence of Multiple @ControllerAdvice @ExceptionHandlers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19498378/setting-precedence-of-multiple-controlleradvice-exceptionhandlers).